# javafx scene builder setting accelerator sets the hot key as "N" instead of "ALT+N" for new menu item under the file menu of a text editor

Tags: javafx, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor, scenebuilder, acceleratorkey

I am creating a text editor using the gluon scene builder with java fx. The scene builder version is SceneBuilder-10.0.0 used with java version "10.0.1". I have a project to build a Text Editor. While building the components in the scene builder, under the File menu, I have the following menu items: New, Open, Save, Save As, and Close. I am trying to set the shortcut keys in the scene builder itself. There is an option to set the accelerator (under the Inspector Panel, in Properties) with a key. However, when I am setting it for the new menu item (and other menu items), it is set as this [ignore ALT+N](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su4JB.png) (Please click on the link to see the image) which makes the short cut key in the text editor to only "N" and not "ALT+N". I tried to code it in the controller class also with setAccelerator(), still it gives me similar results. I even donwloaded a fresh version of the scene builder and still does not work as expected. How can I get the short cut key to be as:

```
New ALT+N
```

under the new menu item, instead of the current:

```
New N
```

Comment: You likely have the modifier set to `ALT_ANY` but I think you meant to set it to `ALT_DOWN`.

Comment: I set the modifier to ALT_ANY. Oh yes, it works when I set it to ALT_DOWN. And now I have ALT+N. But what does ALT_DOWN and ALT_Up mean? Thanks a lot. Was struggling with this the whole day yesterday.

Comment: Now I have another problem. When I set a short cut key for the "File" menu and run the text editor and click ALT+F (for the file menu) with my editor window selected, it does not show me the drop down box with the File menu items (New, Open, Save, Save As, and Close). My shortcut keys for the menu items work fine, but for the File menu, does not work with ALT+F. How do I get the drop down box to work with ALT+F for the File menu?

Comment: The documentation of [`KeyCombination.ModifierValue`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyCombination.ModifierValue.html) explains what `ANY`, `DOWN`, and `UP` mean. Also, your new issue sounds like you're trying to use _mnemonics_, not accelerators. Set the text of the `Menu` to `"_File"` and set [`mnemonicParsing`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/MenuItem.html#mnemonicParsingProperty) to `true`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked too. I am so sorry but, I have an additional problem. I have a font menu under which I have radio button menu items (monospaced, serif, sans-serif) and checkbox menu items (italic, bold). The application does not show the circular graphics next to the radio button menu item names, neither does it show the square graphics next to the checkbox menu item names. They operate perfectly, except for the invisible graphical representation (circle for radio buttons and boxes for checkboxes) next to the menu item names. What can I do to make these show up?

Comment: You should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).